# Is it possible to get a hardcopy in Tmux?

Tags: tmux

I keep flip flopping between tmux and screen, and right now I'm back on the tmux kick. I've been doing some setup for a friend, and I want to make a hard copy of the session so he can see the commands that I've run. I know this is possible in screen, but can I do it with tmux? The man page doesn't seem to have anything related to hardcopy...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not as simple as in `screen`, but it can be done with `capture-pane` and `save-buffer`. The example below will copy the contents of `TARGET` pane (or current pane if none is given) to the file `~/tmux.hardcopy`:

```
tmux capture-pane -t TARGET \; save-buffer -b 0 ~/tmux.hardcopy H
```

Optionally add it as a binding in `tmux.conf`, escaping the ";" as necessary:

```
bind H capture-pane \; save-buffer -b 0 ~/tmux.hardcopy \; delete-buffer -b 0
```

As seen [here](http://pastebin.com/GHCykGs9).

Comment: @Moondoggy: The semi-colons should indeed be escaped, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Also, [asciinema](http://asciinema.org/) is a very nice terminal recorder (text only) that you can use with tmux (or any terminal) if you want to share online.  It uploads to the asciinema site and gives a short link (which you can open with the "url" function in tmux).

It's very nice for tutoring, because beginners can follow the real-time typing more easily than a huge transcript.

It's on github: [sickill/asciinema](https://github.com/sickill/asciinema).

Answer (score 3):

```
script
```

to start recording, and

```
exit
```

to exit the recording session. Tab-autocomplete and delete keys show up a little weird (^G, etc.), though.

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer above resulted in a "No buffer 0" error.
Adding "-b 0" to the capture-pane command fixed that.
I also added "-e" to the capture-pane command to preserve color output.
I also added "-a" to the save-buffer command to append to the output file instead of overwriting.

Here's my answer:

`bind-key h capture-pane -e -b 0 \; save-buffer -a -b 0 ~/tmux.hardcopy \; delete-buffer -b 0 \; display-message "~/tmux.hardcopy updated"`